# Who is Luffy's first mate?

Tags: one-piece

I just started reading the *One Piece* manga and am currently on the 5th and I was wondering who Luffy's first mate is.

Zoro joined first, but Usopp was given permission to take over as captain when Luffy couldn't, which is something only the first mate can do.

Who is Luffy's first mate?

Comment: Officially there is no first mate in SH crew. As you said, Usopp has the permission to act as the captain if Luffy is not there but that is about it. Usually people put Zoro there since he is a serious character and has a "cool vibe" (there were also few comments from other people in OP who though he is the captain) but that is about it. In the end the SH have no first mate.

Comment: I don't remember any scene where in-universe characters misjudge Zorro as the captain. He sure is the most serious one ... until it comes to directions. Can you please reference any scene where ppl think Zorro is the Straw Hats' captain rather than Straw Hat Luffy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Mugiwara no ichimi has no first mate but according to One Piece Yellow: Grand Elements, Roronoa Zoro is referred to as being "like the vice captain". Bartolomeo has also referred to Zoro as the first mate of the Straw Hat Pirates, although, by his own admission, that was just an assumption based on his personal views of the crew.

link here https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/First_Mate

Answer (score 0):

I feel that Zoro would be first mate because usually the first mate is the closest in power to the captain, in this case, that would be Zoro.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references. Opinion-based answers are heavily discouraged.